# droppable only if condition is true

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I got a problem. I have a global variable called $isTutorial.

If it is true, only one cell of my Grid should be droppable,
if it is false, the whole Grid should be droppable.

```
if($isTutorial){
    $('#cell').droppable();
} else if($isTutorial == false){
    $grid.droppable();
}
```

It seems like this way doesn't work. A solution would be to put this code into a function and call this function at the 'start:' dragging event. Is there another solution too?

Comment: Your current implementation seems reasonable. Can you reproduce it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup and/or a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: This seems rather fragile. Why not make them both `.droppable({disabled:true})` and then just call `.droppable('enable')` on the one you need when `$isTutorial` changes? Source: https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: thank you blgt, this is more the way I like it!! :)